# How to generate a scale free network with a desired power law distribution and fixed average degrees via graph-tool?

Tags: python, graph-tool

I'm trying to reproduce the synthetic networks described in some 
papers.

How to create scale-free networks with desired power-law degree 
distributions and fixed average degrees, P(k)=k^(-λ)? The lambda λ values and number of nodes (n) are given, like:

1. n = 50000, λ = 3, 2.7, 2.3, < k >=4, with in a paper
2. n = 4000 and λ = 2.5, or n = 6000 and λ = 3 in the other paper

There is a function called **price_network** in graph-tool which can generate a BA network with λ = 3. However, there is no way to modify the λ value different from 3.

Here are some references:

1. Catastrophic cascade of failures in interdependent networks, Buldyrev et al. 2010, with a separately provided Supplementary Information
2. Small Cluster in Cyber Physical Systems, Huang et al. 2014
3. Catastrophic cascade of failures in interdependent networks, Havlin et al. 2010, this is on the Arxiv and somewhat clarifies the first